# Android Delete Image from SD Card with OnClick

Tags: android, image, gridview, sd-card

I'm trying to simply delete an image from a simple app.  I have it so that when you click on the image, it'll bring up an a dialog with the option to delete it.  I thought this would just be something simple, but everything I have been trying doesn't seem to be doing anything.  Below is my code.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int id = viewIt.getId();

    File file = new File("file://" + arrPath[id]+".jpg");
    file.delete();


    }
});
```

Comment: are you getting any error? please provide any errors you are getting.

Comment: you have not provided the error. make sure you have the following permission in manifest "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Comment: No error message is received.  It just doesn't do anything.  I have already added the permission to the manifest too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Have you added permission in manifest file ?**

Any app that declares the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` **permission** is implicitly granted `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` **permission**.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Get the path of the file required and delete the file

```
File file= new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/myfolder/myimage.jpg");
    if(file.exists())
    {
         file.delete();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't getting the right file path, that is what was throwing it off.

Comment: what would you recommend to dynamically delete a file? I would like to delete whatever file is clicked, not a specific one.  I was trying  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myfolder/" + id + ".jpg" but that didn't work

Comment: if you display a image you need the path. use the same path to delete the file