# Delete Image from Gridview

Tags: android, file, filepath, sd-card

I am trying to simply delete an image from a gridview.  I was having troubles earlier with nothing deleting, but now that isn't a problem since I determined that I just need the correct file path.  The Images are saved on my sd card, so I need help with the code that will correctly identify the right file path of the image that has been clicked, and to delete it when I click the delete button.   What am I doing wrong?  No errors are thrown, and my manifest is up to date on all permissions.  I thought it would be a lot simpler than it has turned out to be.  The following is my code:

```
    deletebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int id = viewIt.getId();
    Log.i("start", "BEGIN_DELETE");
    String myPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/My Directory/";
    File file= new File(myPath + intent.getData());

if(file.exists()){  
    file.delete();
}
    Log.i("end", "END_DELETE");

    dialog.dismiss();                                                                       

    }
    });
```

Comment: Your deleting the file. If the method or class updates and searches for files, I would recommend refreshing that activity as a simple fix or take the long way and actually delete the item on grid view.

Comment: If you are displaying image from a path from sdcard, i would just skip that path and refersh the gridview. Call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter to refresh gridview

Comment: Akyl - I would like to take the long way.  The refresh isn't even the problem.  When I test it out, the image is still on the phone, so it isn't being removed.  What is the long way to to delete it straight from the grid?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Delete Image from SD Card with OnClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052393/android-delete-image-from-sd-card-with-onclick)

Comment: @Raghunandan - not a duplicate, I asked both questions.  In this question, I was struggling with retrieving the File Path, and in the other question, I was having trouble with deleting a file.  I figured it out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! I used a textview to view what file path was getting returned, and then played around with it until I got the correct file path.  Then it worked like a charm.  Below is my working code.

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    int id = viewIt.getId();
                                     Log.i("start", "BEGIN_DELETE");
                                        String filestring = arrPath[id];
                                        filepath.setText(filestring);
                                        File myDir = new File(filestring);
                                        if(myDir.exists()) 
                                        {
                                            myDir.delete();
                                        }
                                        dia.dismiss();
                                        Log.i("end", "END_DELETE"); 

                                }
                            });
```